# How can i start my angular cli project on an ubuntu server?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have just finished my website in `angular2` with `cli`.

I have this project on bitbucket and made on my server

`git clone under var/www/vhosts/.../httpdoc/`

My server settings are also correct because when I go on my server via ip it shows me my index.html, but the website is empty. When i look at my html code i can sea all link and script are included. But in the body i have just:

```
<home></home>
```

nothing more.
It looks for me that he dont do anything with the main.ts.

I have installed node 6.11.0 and npm 3.10.10.
And the node_modules folder is also there.

Can someone help me pls?

Thanks in advance^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you deploy your application to a production server you should build it first. Since you are already using the `ng cli`. In your angular project's root directory run -

`ng build --prod`

Now, you will see a new folder `dist`, which will contain all the necessary  distributable files required to run your application.

You can now copy this `dist` folder to your desired location on the server and run your application.

Notice that inside the `dist` folder you won't have the regular folder structure and files of Angular that you are familiar with during development, rather it contains the `build` version of the application.

**EXTRA**

For running the application, you can use [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

```
 npm install http-server -g
 cd ./dist
 http-server . -p 8000
```

Comment: When i do `ng build --prod` it says that @angular/compiler-cli packag is properly not installed. But I made `npm install --save @angular/compiler-cli` and `npm install -g @angular/cli`. I dont know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: You generated the project with `ng new ProjectName` ,  right ?

Comment: Yes i made `ng new name`

Comment: node v6.11.0 and npm v3.10.10. I have angular/cli and http-server installed as global. And in my project i have all these files: e2e, node_modules, src, .angular-cli.json ..., tsconfig.json and tslint.json

Comment: This is probably because of version incompatibility. try `rm -r node_modules` and `npm install` again updating all the packages to latest versions. Including the globally installed node, npm, ng cli

Comment: yeah that worked. i can do now `ng serve` and all that thx xD

Comment: Don't know if i can ask this her also... I can visit my page now when i type www.....de:8080. How can I see the page without making :8080? Because when i just do www.....de there is a white page

Comment: --prod flag is not required since version 8.0.0 if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`cd` into your project folder and run `npm start`

or

`sudo npm install -g http-server`
After installation cd into your project folder and run `http-server -o.` -o is to open browser to the page.

Comment: Do i need to have the src of website at: at the folder or in folder/src? Because it is still empty after that what you said

Comment: Clone the repository in your home folder. Run `npm start` inside that directory. This will fire up a server. You will get the details of port on the terminal.

Comment: When i do `npm start` i get this error: `The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.`. But i made `npm install -g @angular/cli` at the beginning. But on localhost does it works

Comment: i deleted my repository, unistalled node and npm. After that i installed node with version 6.11.0 and npm 3.10.10. After that i installed global @angular/cli and http-server. Than i made my git clone in httpdoc. But it isn't running. so reinstall didn't worked :/

Comment: add @angular/compiler-cli to package.json and install it (same version as your other @angular libs.

Comment: Try this `npm install --save @angular/compiler-cli`

Comment: @angular/compiler-cli package was not properly installed, but I made `npm install --save @angular/compiler-cli`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to have the `<base href="/">` set differently? in index.html

Comment: I have this in index.html